# 20K celebrations or do we want to cleanup those unanswered questions?

Tags: discussion

[image]

Party time when we hit 20.000 ??

Can't we make 2016 the Cleanup year? I hate it when I hit posts with no answers.

I say start with these 6461 posts with no upvotes, no answers:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+answers%3A0+score%3A0+closed%3Ano+created%3A2000..2015

Yes, there may be comments... but what is more important?

Comment: + there are some really good questions which are not answered. I don't think we should remove such questions. Instead we can mark such questions so that people should have special attention towards it. Like http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/164245/projectpolicy-savepolicy-server-side-giving-error-the-collection-cannot-be

Comment: Ooh, I know, start with this one! http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/168935/drag-and-drop-on-a-web-part-not-working

Comment: If possible can we have one more tab as Recently Answered.  So that user who answer old questions should get noticed and they will be motivated by receiving points by receiving upvote for there answer.  Just a thought,  might not be feasible.  :)

Answer (score 13):

Great suggestion! I'm all in.

First, one could **upvote answers** on questions that have answers with zero score (if they are good enough). Strangely, questions are tagged as "unanswered" even if they have one or several answers which is not accepted, nor upvoted. Or, if the answer is bad, make a better answer.

Second, **answer questions** that doesn't have answers (!). To filter out questions you want to answer, I usually brows to the [my tags view](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags), which makes the list less daunting and keep my (sometimes old) mind focused on this particular topic in SharePoint.

As a last resort, one have the ability to **close *or vote to close*** questions. [Two years ago I started a similar "project" and started to clean up some of the old unanswered questions](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1014/close-old-unanswered-question) with the following:

---

As one possible step in [Cleaning the Archives](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1003/cleaning-the-archives) there is a suggestion on closing old unanswered questions. By definition, an unanswered question is

1. A question which doesn't have any answers
2. A question with no upvoted answers

By old question, we will define that as a question older than three months, and where the poster of the question hasn't been seen in three months. Either, users with enough reputation could cast a close vote and users without could flag the question with the same reason:

> This question appears to be off-topic because it is older than three months, the poster of the question hasn't been seen for three months and it contains no answers or no upvoted answers.

[image]

If the original poster (OP) of the question returns, and want to have the question reopened - it will be reopened if it's closed for the reasons mentioned above.

Comment: When I try to flag a question, `Flagging` > `Closing` > `Off Topic`. I do not see an option `Other` as you have shown in image in your answer. The only option which allows me to put in comments which you have described is `in need of moderator intervention`. Will that be an appropriate one to flag? Or it will cause too much of a pressure on Moderator.

Comment: @AsadRefai No, its not too much preassure, please flag the questions meeting the criteria - and we'll close them. Thank you!

Comment: Obligatory xkcd: https://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: @LiveForever No I don’t. That’s why I recommend giving answers first before closing the abandoned question.